# Transition element from height 0 to 100, starting from bottom

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Im tryng to make my modal transition from bottom to top when activated, i having no luck with `transform-origin: bottom`, made a sample codepen

HTML

```
<div class="main"> 

  <div class="hidden">HOVER</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.main{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;

}
.hidden{
 height: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;

}
.hidden:hover{
  height:200px;
  -webkit-transition:height 1s;
}
```

https://codepen.io/danielkmx/pen/OevOLW

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you but this might flicker a bit.

```
.main{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;

}
.hidden{
 height: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transition: all 1.0s;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;


}
.hidden:hover{
  height:200px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all 1.0s;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a relative/absolute position combination for the two DIVs (parent relative, child absolute) and according position settings in relation to the `bottom` of the parent:

```css
.main {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.hidden {
  height: 16px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

.hidden:hover {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="hidden">HOVER</div>
</div>
```